# Keeping a geolocation service running?

Tags: android, service, geolocation

I'm asked to do an app that would run a geolocation service during some employees working time. I've got a few questions about that:

-Is it possible to have a service running as long as the user doesn't stop it (start/stop button)?. From my understanding a service is bound to an activity, which can be killed anytime by Android...

-What's the best way to do some location tracking in terms of battery life? Is it the same to 1/create, get an update and delete a LocationManager every x seconds and 2/to create once a LocationManager and set the `minTime` arg in LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates to x?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes it is possible to keep a service running for as long as the user (or in times of a resource crunch, the system) does not kill it. A service that has to run this way should override the

```
onStartCommand()
```

method and be started via

```
Context.startService()
```

What you are referring to are services that override onBind() and are started via

```
context.bindService()
```

Read the Service documentation, it contains a description of the lifecycles of both kinds of services.

2) One of the best guides for best practices for geo-location is written [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) by Reto Meier. Check it out

Comment: If the activity which is bound to the service is killed by the system, then the service is killed, right?

Comment: The service gets killed as a side effect of the binder object being leaked. So yeah for all intents and purposes, if the service is *bound* to the activity, it'll get killed off. 

However, if the service was started with Context.startService() then it's lifecycle is not bound to an activity or anything.

Comment: You mentioned a service being bound to an activity. Not really. Any class with access to a context object should be able to start a bound service. Yes, the most sensible use is with activities, but its not the only place where its possible.